# How are constants initialized in Objective-C header files?

Tags: objective-c, header, constants

How do you initialise a constant in a header file?

For example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

  const int foo;

}

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init:{?????;}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For "public" constants, you declare it as `extern` in your header file (.h) and initialize it in your implementation file (.m).

```
// File.h
extern int const foo;
```

then

```
// File.m
int const foo = 42;
```

Consider using `enum` if it's not just one, but multiple constants belonging together

Comment: What if I need `typedef NS_ENUM`?

Answer (score 12):

Objective C classes do not support constants as members.  You can't create a constant the way you want.

The closest way to declare a constant associated with a class is to define a class method that returns it.  You can also use extern to access constants directly.  Both are demonstrated below:

```
// header
extern const int MY_CONSTANT;

@interface Foo
{
}

+(int) fooConstant;

@end

// implementation

const int MY_CONSTANT = 23;

static const int FOO_CONST = 34;

@implementation Foo

+(int) fooConstant
{
    return FOO_CONST; // You could also return 34 directly with no static constant
}

@end
```

An advantage of the class method version is that it can be extended to provide constant objects quite easily.  You can use extern objects, nut you have to initialise them in an initialize method (unless they are strings).  So you will often see the following pattern:

```
// header
@interface Foo
{
}

+(Foo*) fooConstant;

@end

// implementation

@implementation Foo

+(Foo*) fooConstant
{
    static Foo* theConstant = nil;
    if (theConstant == nil)
    {
        theConstant = [[Foo alloc] initWithStuff];
    }
    return theConstant;
}

@end
```

Comment: Added another bit that I just thought of

Comment: nice. It might be interesting to specify that the pattern you wrote is called singleton and is often used for sharing stuff all accross applications. A nice example in iPhone dev is the AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way for value type constants like integers is to use the [enum hack](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter08_023.html) as hinted by unbeli.

```
// File.h
enum {
    SKFoo = 1,
    SKBar = 42,
};
```

One advantage to this over using `extern` is that it's all resolved at compile time so there no memory is needed to hold the variables.

Another method is to use `static const` which is what was to replace the enum hack in C/C++.

```
// File.h
static const int SKFoo = 1;
static const int SKBar = 42;
```

A quick scan through Apple's headers shows that the enum hack method appears to be the preferred way of doing this in Objective-C and I actually find it cleaner and use it myself.

Also, if you are creating groups of options you should consider using `NS_ENUM` to create a typesafe constants.

```
// File.h
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SKContants) {
    SKFoo = 1,
    SKBar = 42,
};
```

More info on `NS_ENUM` and it's cousin `NS_OPTIONS` is available at [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/).